# Naming conventions in azure

Tags: azure, sharepoint

We recently encountered an issue where in the naming conventions for SharePoint service accounts hosted in azure were misleading.
The spfarm account was named as sqladmin..
The team that handles this had no response for this and mentioned they haven't done any changes.

Can anyone please let me know if this is a common case scenario or is it that someone changed the account name?

Comment: Sure they didn't. Nor did they install the farm using the DBA account because they didn't bother to [follow the security guidance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/plan-for-administrative-and-service-accounts)

Comment: `SQLAdmin` isn't any kind of common account. Someone explicitly created that account. Typically, installing a SharePoint farm requires elevated privileges because the installation has to create databases and tables but people *don't* use the DBA account for that. Finally, in SharePoint Online you don't have access      
 to the service accounts, so I assume you're talking about a VM. Who installed the farm? What accounts did they use? Those accounts weren't created by themselves, they are domain accounts

Answer (score 0):

If you're still in the early stages, you can try deploying it again using the quickstart template here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/templates/sharepoint-server-farm-ha/